# Magento 2 showing another header color in mobile layout

Tags: magento2, logo

I have just installed Magento 2 with freego as theme.
When the site is showing on  a computer screen, the background of the header area is dark, so therefore I put in a white logo.
The problem is when the site is shown on mobile screens under 767px (I think), the header area turns white. I was thinking about using the same logo in black on the mobile layout as the other icons in header also changes colour.
Which file(s) needs to be edited? Or how is this possible to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code below in a **_extend.less** file under **app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego_child\web\css\source**. If file and folders does not exist, create it.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @width-767) {
.logo{
    img {
    content:url("../images/dhtlogo.png");
    }
} 
}
```

Then run **"bin/magento setup:upgrade”** with ssh to update files on website.